# Matlab powers of m

Tags: matlab

I tried the following code out.

```
syms m;
0.2^m
```

From this got (1/5)^m as the answer but I need to keep this as 0.2^m. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please expand and post an example of the expected result.

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't know why you cannot understand what I have explained as simple as I can. When I type the above code the answer i get is of the form (1/5)^m which is in a fractional form. I want it to be in the form (0.2)^m which is in decimal form. What I have given is an example

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior when creating symbolic objects is to use the rational form: check [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html)

Hence you need to specify that you want decimal representation using the following.

```
clear
syms m
F = sym(0.2,'d')^m %// d stands for decimal

F =

0.20000000000000001110223024625157^m
```

As mentioned in the doc,

> The number of digits is taken from the current setting of digits used
>   by vpa. You can change this as well.

Comment: thanks but how did 0.2 become 0.20000000000000001110223024625157? can't we just get 0.2

Comment: check out the link it explains how come digits are represented like so. It's because of floating-point arithmetic and MATLAB trying to represent within 16 significant figures the decimal number closest to an actual fraction (in your case 1/5). I can't say why is that but you should not be worried about that.